Django startproject [WinError2]
When I try to create a new project using:
django-admin startproject main

I get this error:
CommandError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\edgar\\Documents\\main'

I thought django creates this directory? That's what I see in all tutorials.
I tried running the Command Prompt as an Administrator, as well as uninstalling and reinstalling django. I also tried reinstalling python, and also running in VSCode terminal instead. Nothing seems to be working. If I manually create the directory, then I get an error saying 'manage.py' does not exist in the directory.

Did you add environment variable ?
if not
Then first press window + r an window box appear in that type APPDATA press enter an window appears with some folder's click on local inside local click on programs now go in python again python now finally click on Scrips folder now copy all this folder path .
Ok now search environment open it inside that window select advance tab then click on environment variable now appear an other window where you need to past that path which you  coped just click of top box path and past it  .
